# Image validation in Edit form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a issue, Please take a look below.

I have a edit user profile section where we update user account, i want to check if no image exists in table & user too not provided image then we have to validate the image & show an error. if there is already a image exists in table then no image validation suppose to check. Everything works good except image validation.

i am using from request for validation. below is my validation rules in request file.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_type' =>'required',
        'first_name' =>'required|max:100',
        'last_name' =>'required|max:100',
        'email' =>'required|email|max:100',
        'image' =>'required|image',
        'zip_code' =>'required|numeric|min:5',
    ];
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.2, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i figure out the solution using help of @Amir. below is the complete solutions of this issue.

//add this in user model

```
public function notHavingImageInDb(){
    return (empty($this->image))?true:false;
    //return true;
}
```

//import the User model & Auth class in request class.

```
use App\User;
use Auth;
```

//add this in from request

```
public function rules()
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());

        $rules =  [
            'user_type' =>'required',
            'first_name' =>'required|max:100',
            'last_name' =>'required|max:100',
            'email' =>'required|email|max:100',
            'image' =>'image',
            'zip_code' =>'required|numeric|min:5',
        ];

        if ($user->notHavingImageInDb()){
            $rules['image'] = 'required|image';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

Now all done.

In the above code we check if the column has some value or not in validation, if yes then model function return true, this make the if condition active in request class, else, if condition remain inactive. works like charm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Conditionally Adding Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules):

so something like:

```
  $v->sometimes(['image'], 'required|image', function($input) use ($user)  {
      return $user->notHavingImageInDb();
  });
```

you can also use plain logic like:

```
public function rules()
{
   $roles = [
            'user_type' =>'required',
            'first_name' =>'required|max:100',
            'last_name' =>'required|max:100',
            'email' =>'required|email|max:100',
            'image' =>'image',
            'zip_code' =>'required|numeric|min:5',
           ];

    if ($user->notHavingImageInDb())
      $rules['image'] = 'required|image';

    return $rules
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother for replying.

But i don't want default image validation, i just want it if no image present in db and user too doesn't provide the image. so i don't think so we add the required rule for image.

apart from this where do i need to add the below code.

$v->sometimes(['image'], 'required|image', function($input) use ($user)  {
      return $user->notHavingImageInDb();
});

Comment: just change the logic to whatever you need, use the second example, if (no image present in db and user too doesn't provide the image) add the validation to the rules

Comment: "I can only show you the door. You're the one that has to walk through it."

Comment: i post the answer here . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064849/image-validation-in-edit-form-in-laravel-5-2/39067430#39067430

Answer (score 1):

You can create another request class and name it UserUpdateRequest with artisan 
like

```
php artisan make:request UserUpdateRequest
```

in this request class you just have to remove 'required' it will be like that

```
'image' => 'image'
```

and set UserUpdateResuest as parameter to update method like

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $userUpdateRequest, $id){
    //
}
```